# Can not determine the module class x Component in location/x.component.ts add x component to Ng Module to fix it. Angular 4

Tags: angular

It shows the error:

> Cannot determine the module for class CCURLActionComponent in C:/Users/HP/Desktop/default-2/default/src/app/content/pages/header/action/aslaAction/aslaActionURL/asla-url-action.component.ts! Add CCURLActionComponent to the NgModule to fix it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'm-action',
  templateUrl: './cc-url-action.component.html',
  providers: [PagesService],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CCURLActionComponent implements OnInit {
  htmlContent = '';
  textAnalyticsInput:any;
  textAnalyticsResponse:any;
  polarity:any;
}
```

Above code is same for cc-url-action.component and asla-url-action.component in ts file

In pages.module.ts:

```
import { CCURLActionComponent } from "./header/action/CCAction/CCActionURL/cc-url-action.component";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        PagesComponent,
        ActionComponent,
        ActionURLComponent,
        CCURLActionComponent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by changing this-

In aslaURLActionComponent component:-

@Injectable()
export  class  aslaURLActionComponent  extends CCURLActionComponent implements OnInit {
}

And in Ng Module:-

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        PagesComponent,
        ActionComponent,
        ActionURLComponent,
        CCURLActionComponent,
       aslaURLActionComponent
   ]
})